# iOS: Alphabetical sections for tableview from API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I am getting a list of customer names from an API. I have about 11,000 names and am then displaying them in a searchable table view. I would like to create sections just like the address book where it has the letters of the alphabet and the index on the right. All the tutorials I have seen mentioned using fetchRequests but since I am getting the info from an API I don't think that will work.

Can someone help me make it so I can display the list with section headers and an index on the right? I already have it set to just display the names and it is searchable.

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSMutableArray *tempCustomers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        //self.customers = [json objectForKey:@"data"];
        for (NSDictionary *dict in [json objectForKey:@"data"]) {
            //NSLog(@"Dict: %@, %@",[dict objectForKey:@"last_name"], [dict objectForKey:@"first_name"]);
            [tempCustomers addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",[dict objectForKey:@"last_name"],[dict objectForKey:@"first_name"]]];
            //NSLog(@"Size: %i - %@", tempCustomers.count, [tempCustomers lastObject]);
        }
        self.customers = tempCustomers;
        //NSLog(@"Received: %@",tempCustomers);
        NSLog(@"Customers Count: %i", self.customers.count);
        tempCustomers = nil;
```

EDIT:
Is this the best way to proceed if I am going to have thousands of names?

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSMutableArray *tempCustomers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString *name;
        customerSections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        //self.customers = [json objectForKey:@"data"];
        for (NSDictionary *dict in [json objectForKey:@"data"]) {
            name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",[dict objectForKey:@"last_name"],[dict objectForKey:@"first_name"]];
            //NSLog(@"Dict: %@, %@",[dict objectForKey:@"last_name"], [dict objectForKey:@"first_name"]);
            [tempCustomers addObject:name];
            if (![customerSections containsObject:[[name substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]]) {
                [customerSections addObject:[[name substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];
            }
            //NSLog(@"Size: %i - %@", tempCustomers.count, [tempCustomers lastObject]);
        }
        NSLog(@"Full customer Sections %@",customerSections);
        self.customers = tempCustomers;
        //NSLog(@"Received: %@",tempCustomers);
        NSLog(@"Customers Count: %i", self.customers.count);
        tempCustomers = nil;
```

UPDATE 2:
I changed the array to a dictionary where the key is the letter and the value is the index that key starts at. Right now it is displaying weird numbers. See log below.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [customerSections count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Section: %i", section);
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return self.filteredCustomers.count;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Section before conversion %@, %@",[customerSections objectForKey:[[customerSections allKeys] objectAtIndex:section]],[[customerSections allKeys] objectAtIndex:section]);
        NSInteger current = (NSInteger)[customerSections objectForKey:[[customerSections allKeys] objectAtIndex:section]];
        //NSString *next = [customerSections objectForKey:[[customerSections allKeys] objectAtIndex:section + 1]];
        if ((NSInteger)[customerSections objectForKey:[[customerSections allKeys] lastObject]] != current) {
            NSLog(@"Returning count: %i which was %@ - %@",(NSInteger)[customerSections objectForKey:[[customerSections allKeys] objectAtIndex:section + 1]] - current,[customerSections objectForKey:[[customerSections allKeys] objectAtIndex:section + 1]] ,current);
            return (NSInteger)[customerSections objectForKey:[[customerSections allKeys] objectAtIndex:section + 1]] - current;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Returning last count %i of %i - %i",self.customers.count - current, self.customers.count, current);
            return self.customers.count - current;
        }
        return self.customers.count;
    }
}
```

LOG
2012-01-19 10:42:38.751 MyApp[9900:11503] Full customer Sections {
    " " = 22;
    "(" = 30;
    "," = 0;
    "." = 31;
    1 = 42;
    2 = 43;
    "?" = 44;
    A = 46;
    B = 407;
    C = 1156;
    D = 1820;
    E = 2304;
    F = 2508;
    G = 2833;
    H = 3290;
    I = 3869;
    J = 3898;
    K = 4166;
    L = 4546;
    M = 5047;
    N = 5888;
    O = 6070;
    P = 6224;
    Q = 6706;
    R = 6725;
    S = 7200;
    T = 8114;
    U = 8461;
    V = 8498;
    W = 8666;
    X = 9129;
    Y = 9134;
    Z = 9197;
}

```
2012-01-19 10:42:38.752 MyApp[9900:11503] Customers Count: 9258
2012-01-19 10:42:38.753 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 32 - J
2012-01-19 10:42:38.753 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 32
2012-01-19 10:42:38.754 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 3898, J
2012-01-19 10:42:38.754 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning last count -269873302 of 9258 - 269882560
2012-01-19 10:42:38.755 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 0 - K
2012-01-19 10:42:38.755 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 0
2012-01-19 10:42:38.756 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 4166, K
2012-01-19 10:42:38.756 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 42608 which was 4546 - 4166
2012-01-19 10:42:38.757 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 1 - L
2012-01-19 10:42:38.758 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 1
2012-01-19 10:42:38.758 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 4546, L
2012-01-19 10:42:38.759 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 56432 which was 5047 - 4546
2012-01-19 10:42:38.759 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 2 - M
2012-01-19 10:42:38.760 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 2
2012-01-19 10:42:38.760 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 5047, M
2012-01-19 10:42:38.761 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 94528 which was 5888 - 5047
2012-01-19 10:42:38.762 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 3 - N
2012-01-19 10:42:38.763 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 3
2012-01-19 10:42:38.763 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 5888, N
2012-01-19 10:42:38.768 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 20368 which was 6070 - 5888
2012-01-19 10:42:38.769 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 4 - O
2012-01-19 10:42:38.769 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 4
2012-01-19 10:42:38.770 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 6070, O
2012-01-19 10:42:38.771 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: -695200 which was 22 - 6070
2012-01-19 10:42:38.771 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 5 -  
2012-01-19 10:42:38.771 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 5
2012-01-19 10:42:38.772 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 22,  
2012-01-19 10:42:38.772 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 712496 which was 6224 - 22
2012-01-19 10:42:38.780 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 6 - P
2012-01-19 10:42:38.781 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 6
2012-01-19 10:42:38.781 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 6224, P
2012-01-19 10:42:38.782 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 54080 which was 6706 - 6224
2012-01-19 10:42:38.782 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 7 - Q
2012-01-19 10:42:38.783 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 7
2012-01-19 10:42:38.783 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 6706, Q
2012-01-19 10:42:38.784 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 2128 which was 6725 - 6706
2012-01-19 10:42:38.784 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 8 - R
2012-01-19 10:42:38.785 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 8
2012-01-19 10:42:38.785 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 6725, R
2012-01-19 10:42:38.786 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 53440 which was 7200 - 6725
2012-01-19 10:42:38.786 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 9 - S
2012-01-19 10:42:38.787 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 9
2012-01-19 10:42:38.787 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 7200, S
2012-01-19 10:42:38.788 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 102576 which was 8114 - 7200
2012-01-19 10:42:38.789 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 10 - T
2012-01-19 10:42:38.790 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 10
2012-01-19 10:42:38.790 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 8114, T
2012-01-19 10:42:38.791 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 38992 which was 8461 - 8114
2012-01-19 10:42:38.791 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 11 - U
2012-01-19 10:42:38.792 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 11
2012-01-19 10:42:38.792 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 8461, U
2012-01-19 10:42:38.793 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 4192 which was 8498 - 8461
2012-01-19 10:42:38.793 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 12 - V
2012-01-19 10:42:38.794 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 12
2012-01-19 10:42:38.794 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 8498, V
2012-01-19 10:42:38.794 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: -965296 which was 44 - 8498
2012-01-19 10:42:38.795 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 13 - ?
2012-01-19 10:42:38.795 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 13
2012-01-19 10:42:38.796 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 44, ?
2012-01-19 10:42:38.796 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 984192 which was 8666 - 44
2012-01-19 10:42:38.804 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 14 - W
2012-01-19 10:42:38.805 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 14
2012-01-19 10:42:38.805 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 8666, W
2012-01-19 10:42:38.805 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: -985776 which was 30 - 8666
2012-01-19 10:42:38.806 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 15 - (
2012-01-19 10:42:38.806 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 15
2012-01-19 10:42:38.807 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 30, (
2012-01-19 10:42:38.807 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 1037712 which was 9129 - 30
2012-01-19 10:42:38.815 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 16 - X
2012-01-19 10:42:38.816 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 16
2012-01-19 10:42:38.816 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 9129, X
2012-01-19 10:42:38.817 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: -1035568 which was 46 - 9129
2012-01-19 10:42:38.817 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 17 - A
2012-01-19 10:42:38.817 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 17
2012-01-19 10:42:38.833 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 46, A
2012-01-19 10:42:38.834 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 1036048 which was 9134 - 46
2012-01-19 10:42:38.842 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 18 - Y
2012-01-19 10:42:38.843 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 18
2012-01-19 10:42:38.843 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 9134, Y
2012-01-19 10:42:38.843 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: -1799248 which was 407 - 9134
2012-01-19 10:42:38.844 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 19 - B
2012-01-19 10:42:38.844 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 19
2012-01-19 10:42:38.845 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 407, B
2012-01-19 10:42:38.845 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 1806464 which was 9197 - 407
2012-01-19 10:42:38.858 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 20 - Z
2012-01-19 10:42:38.859 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 20
2012-01-19 10:42:38.863 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 9197, Z
2012-01-19 10:42:38.864 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: -1890576 which was 1156 - 9197
2012-01-19 10:42:38.864 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 21 - C
2012-01-19 10:42:38.865 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 21
2012-01-19 10:42:38.866 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 1156, C
2012-01-19 10:42:38.866 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 842016 which was 0 - 1156
2012-01-19 10:42:38.873 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 22 - ,
2012-01-19 10:42:38.874 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 22
2012-01-19 10:42:38.875 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 0, ,
2012-01-19 10:42:38.875 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: -916544 which was 1820 - 0
2012-01-19 10:42:38.876 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 23 - D
2012-01-19 10:42:38.876 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 23
2012-01-19 10:42:38.876 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 1820, D
2012-01-19 10:42:38.877 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: -54048 which was 2304 - 1820
2012-01-19 10:42:38.877 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 24 - E
2012-01-19 10:42:38.878 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 24
2012-01-19 10:42:38.878 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 2304, E
2012-01-19 10:42:38.879 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 973920 which was 31 - 2304
2012-01-19 10:42:38.886 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 25 - .
2012-01-19 10:42:38.887 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 25
2012-01-19 10:42:38.887 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 31, .
2012-01-19 10:42:38.887 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 294144 which was 2508 - 31
2012-01-19 10:42:38.890 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 26 - F
2012-01-19 10:42:38.891 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 26
2012-01-19 10:42:38.891 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 2508, F
2012-01-19 10:42:38.892 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 36432 which was 2833 - 2508
2012-01-19 10:42:38.892 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 27 - G
2012-01-19 10:42:38.893 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 27
2012-01-19 10:42:38.893 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 2833, G
2012-01-19 10:42:38.893 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 51264 which was 3290 - 2833
2012-01-19 10:42:38.894 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 28 - H
2012-01-19 10:42:38.895 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 28
2012-01-19 10:42:38.895 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 3290, H
2012-01-19 10:42:38.896 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: -380576 which was 42 - 3290
2012-01-19 10:42:38.896 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 29 - 1
2012-01-19 10:42:38.897 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 29
2012-01-19 10:42:38.897 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 42, 1
2012-01-19 10:42:38.897 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 445376 which was 3869 - 42
2012-01-19 10:42:38.901 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 30 - I
2012-01-19 10:42:38.902 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 30
2012-01-19 10:42:38.902 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 3869, I
2012-01-19 10:42:38.903 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: -445312 which was 43 - 3869
2012-01-19 10:42:38.903 MyApp[9900:f803] Title for Section: 31 - 2
2012-01-19 10:42:38.904 MyApp[9900:f803] Section: 31
2012-01-19 10:42:38.904 MyApp[9900:f803] Section before conversion 43, 2
2012-01-19 10:42:38.905 MyApp[9900:f803] Returning count: 448816 which was 3898 - 43
```

FINAL EDIT:
I went with `UILocalizedCollation` and this tutorial http://benedictcohen.co.uk/blog/archives/230

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were using CoreData, you would be using fetchRequests, and perhaps a fetchedResultsController.... but you're not using CoreData, so forget about that stuff...

What you want to look at are the `UITableView` data source methods `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` and `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:`. The first method is where you'll return your index titles, probably an NSArray containing the strings @"A", @"B", etc. The second method helps the table view know where to find the data for the section from your data source. You should read up on these methods, as they are critical to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: would it be best in sectionIndexTitlesForTableView to do a loop through all 11,000 customers to get the first letters or use predicate?

Comment: Well... that's a LOT of data. You're best bet _might_ be to find the section titles as you parse it from the server _if_ you're receiving it pre-sorted. That's kind of the key: when and where is it sorted? Once it's sorted, you can collect the section titles you have AND the index where each new title begins in your dataset (that's what the second method wants you to return, above).

Comment: it is sorted server side so I get them alphabetically using NSJSONSerialization

Comment: btw examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please look at the OP I made an edit. Would the below code be the best approach?

Comment: You're on the right track with locating each unique index letter. But you need to keep track of where in your list of customers each new section starts. So for each letter you should record with it `[tempCustomers count]`. That is to say, your `customerSections` should be a dictionary (not an array) mapping each letter to the index into `tempCustomers` where that section begins.

Comment: Thanks, I am attempting what you are doing but running into issues. Please see OP.

Comment: Use %d, not %i, first of all in your NSLog statements... Those values are certainly not right due to using the wrong formatting placeholder. You can see that your data is not as clean as you think it is, as evidenced by the fact that your first sections have titles of "", "(", ",", ".", "1", "2", and "?". Perhaps that is OK for you; I don't know. That aside, your dictionary of section names/indices looks right, at least given what I know about your app and the data. :-) Anyway, what's your app look like now? Did you implement those 2 data source methods I mentioned initially?

Comment: no i haven't, I am wanting to get the sections working first before I add the indexes on the side.

Comment: Oh, well, they sort of go hand in hand. :-) By the way, your returned array of section index titles is now easily created with the expression `[customerSections allKeys]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! You ended up getting me on the right track. I went ahead and went with this way using UILocalizedIndexedCollation

Comment: Cool. I have to be honest here: I did not know about `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` until just now. +1 for teaching me something, too. :-)